# Count the number of match words inside a table using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Inside a table there are words "CRITICAL" and "SAFE", I want to count how many CRITICAL are there inside the table. And as possible, please don't add class name or id name.

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td>CRTICAL</td>
 <td>CRTICAL</td>
 <td>CRTICAL</td>
 <td>SAFE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>SAFE</td>
 <td>CRTICAL</td>
 <td>CRTICAL</td>
 <td>CRTICAL</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Use `:contains` in JS (jQuery) https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_contains.asp  For example `var elements = $('td:contains(CRITICAL)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :contains in JS (jQuery)

```js
var test = $('td:contains(CRTICAL)');

console.log(test.size());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
 <td>CRTICAL</td>
 <td>CRTICAL</td>
 <td>CRTICAL</td>
 <td>SAFE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>SAFE</td>
 <td>CRTICAL</td>
 <td>CRTICAL</td>
 <td>CRTICAL</td>
</tr>
</table>
```